# what is difference between different syntax in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

what is the difference between:

```
$(function() {

//.....

});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//......

});
```

in jQuery coding?

Comment: You might also add a third solution: `jQuery(function($){ ... })` to prevent `$` conflicts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing. It does actually exactly the same, it's just a shortcut so you have to write less code.